# How to use psycopg2 with multithreaded flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, psycopg2, flask-socketio

I have a flaskSocketIo python server (it use eventlet), this server works in multithreading.
Each of my endpoints needs to run multiple requests on a postgresql database.
I tried several approaches but I cannot find the solution to my problem:

- One connection by endpoint, it works well but when I put my server
  under heavy load (1000 simultaneous request) the connection time to
  the database takes too long and I get response times of 5.6 seconds
- One general connection between my server and my database and a function
  to execute queries. I'm getting error because different threads are
  trying to access single sign-on at the same time.

What is the solution for not having to create a connection to the database for each endpoint in order to obtain correct response times?

Comment: You could use a [connection pool](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/pool.html)

Comment: I tried and the error is the same I get connection with pool.getconn() by endpoint and the response time is much too long